# Simple directive that uses TemplateRef yields "No provider for TemplateRef"

Tags: angular

I'm trying to create a directive that creates a view based upon a condition. Just like the built in `ngIf` directive.

This is all I added to my project:

```
export class QueryNameContext {
    public name: string;
}

@Directive({
    selector: '[action]'
})
export class QueryNameDirective {
    @Input('action')
    public name: string;

    public constructor(private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef,
                       private templateRef: TemplateRef<QueryNameContext>) {
    }
}
```

When I try to use the directive in a template:

```
<div *action="thing"></div>
```

I get this dependency error:

```
core.es5.js:1020 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No provider for TemplateRef!
```

My modules are importing `CommonModule` and I'm able to use `TemplateRef` in `@ViewChild` bindings of other directives.

I can't see what I've done wrong.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe someone will run into this problem so I'll leave this here.

I had **two** directives with the same selector by mistake. Renaming this fixed the `Uncaught (in promise): Error: No provider for TemplateRef!` error.

Comment: so how did it affect this? did one of the directives wasn't a structural directive?

Comment: @Maximus I had a component with a selector `"action"` and a directive with an attribute selector `"[action]"`. I would had thought this would separate them enough. I should do a plunker and submit a bug issue, but I'm not sure that is the exact way to reproduce it.

Comment: and how did your html look like?

Comment: Same problem I was also facing, but for me the reason was not appending * in front of it  `*customif="true"` . As this is the first result coming in google , it might help someone

Comment: @PranoySarkar thank you mate! I almost added asterix, but forgot to hit Ctrl+S and voila no provider error

Comment: Thanks Pranoy, you saved my day

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem, but i my case I had structural directive `'[user]'` and the error was caused by components that have `@Input() user`, so this binding were conflict with directive due to the same name.

Time to change directive name =)